# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041098"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, esri-arc-engine

Everyone. I need to use union of every three sequence raster in database, so I use `ILogicalOp.BooleanAnd`. Weirdly I receive `{"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041098"}` in third time of `for` loop.

Here is part of my code: error appear on `temp=…` In the following line when `i==2`.

```
      ILogicalOp RMath;
      for (int i = 0; i < inputRas.Length-2; i=i+1)
      {
          temp = RMath.BooleanAnd(inputRas[i], inputRas[i+1]);
          rasOut = RMath.BooleanAnd(temp, inputRas[i + 2]);
      }
```

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: What value does `inputRas.Length` return?

Comment: inputRas is an array of rasters that I want to  3 by 3 union them. so I need to get its length in order to make the count down of database. I think that the problem is due to null in rasters which made mistake is there any way in C++ to convert null to zero for raster. There is some in python like Con(IsNull(inRaster01), 0, inRaster01).

Comment: In C++, null and zero are almost always the same (ignoring strong typing with `nullptr`), you probably just need to do the call conditionally ... `if (whatever != 0) ...` etc.

Comment: In these process null and zero have difference as result of Boolean OR with null make it null.It is a stand alone software that I am creating. if I get your meaning correctly, u said I should go to each raster pixels and do conditions with them. I am concern that doing such stuff make the possess time so long.

Comment: Maybe we're not understanding each other, but I was thinking that your `inputRas` array has null entries, so the test would be something like `if (inputRas[i] != nullptr) ...` and so on. Does that make sense? Also, are you using native C++ or C++/CLI (i.e. .NET)?

Comment: no there are some pixels of each raster null, which make a case difficult. I am using Visual studio 10.